# List files inside a shared drive folder in spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to list all the files I have in a shared drive in a spreadsheet with their name and the URL link.

I came across the following Google script

```
function findFilesInfo() {

  const folderId = '1vNaHwTQ2WObU9Hil5GMqXdiokYp5wfDH'
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
  const files = folder.getFiles()
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = source.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const data = [];
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
      const childFile = files.next();
      var info = [ 
        childFile.getName(), 
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getLastUpdated(),  
      ];
    
    data.push(info);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

[From the following question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457627/list-files-inside-a-google-drive-folder-in-spreadsheets)

I tried to implement it and it's working for my own personal drive, but when I change the ID to a shared drive, it keeps giving me the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 20, file "get name")`

I tried removing the `data.length` or set a specific number for the getRange function, it all gives me the same error.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: try using Drives.list

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
sheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

by

```
if(data.length > 0) sheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

The above because the error message will occur when the folder hasn't any file.

Related Q/A about working with subfolders

- [Iterate Through Folders/Subfolders/Files in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25145137/1595451)
- [I need to list all the files in subfolders using google script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37394300/1595451)
- [How to list also files inside subfolders in google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59045664/1595451)
- [How best to delete all files in a folder and its subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65407497/1595451)

Comment: Ahh I see! Ok well follow up questions, that folder actually contained sub-folders, so is this why it was returning as empty? If yes, then how can I tweak the script so it keeps opening the sub folders? Thanks!

Comment: @Mike I added some links that might help you.